# Error connection to remote server in socket programming using c

Tags: c, windows, sockets

It is a sample code where i have tried to pass a request to server and get me the desired data. 
But my connect to remote server code is not working as i thought.

```
if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected");
```

I don't know why value of the condition is getting below zero.Why connection is not getting done?

Full code:

```
    /*
    Create a TCP socket
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");

    //Send some data
    message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Data Send\n");

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    puts("Reply received\n");

    //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `puts("connect error");` try `perror("connect")`, or use the result of `WSAGetLastError()` as you are doing elsewhere. Then you will see for yourself what the problem is. Don't make up your own vague error messages when the system already provides precise ones. And reporting your own error message here instead of the system's is just a waste of everybody's time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initalize the whole sockaddr_in to zero before assigning to it.

```
memset( &server, 0, sizeof(server) );
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.235.20");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 80 );
```

I copied your code and tried it out and it seemed to work, maybe you have a firewall that is interfering.

BTW I changed your inet_addr call to

```
InetPtonA( AF_INET, "74.125.235.20", &server.sin_addr.s_addr );
```